# CK Finder Upload Plugin not loading in Opera

Tags: plugin, file-manager

Just back to work from the Christmas break and for some reason when I try to upload images in the CK Finder File Manager I get a message saying "Couldn't load plugin", this only seems to be in Opera though, when I try in Firefox it works fine. Has Opera stopped being supported or something like that?

Comment: Which add-on are you using which uses CK Finder in its fieldtype?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've realised it was an issue with the Adobe Flash plugin, I've updated it from here https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ and it all seems to be working normally now.